# New at programing and having trouble with jquery click event

Tags: jquery

I start this by generating 4 characters in my startgame function and sent them to my Character Div. Then I need to click on one of the 4(vader, stormtrooper, luke or yoda). When I click on one of the 4. The other 3 will move from that Div and go to the enemiesavailable div. While the one that I clicked will stay in the Character Div. I can not figure out how to accomplish this. I have only been coding for 4 weeks.
my code is

```js
    
    var characters = [{
            name: "DarthVader",
            health: 120,
            attack: 8,
            enemyattackback: 15,
            imgURL: "assests/images/darth_vader.jpg"
        },
    
        {
            name: "StormTrooper",
            health: 100,
            attack: 14,
            enemyattackback: 5,
            imgURL: "assests/images/stormtrooper.jpg"
        },
    
        {
            name: "LukeSkywalker",
            health: 150,
            attack: 8,
            enemyattackback: 20,
            imgURL: "assests/images/Luke_Skywalker.jpg"
    
        },
    
        {
            name: "Yoda",
            health: 180,
            attack: 7,
            enemyattackback: 20,
            imgURL: "assests/images/yoda.jpg"
        }
    ];
    var selectedCharacter;
    var enemys = [];
    var figheter;
    var yoda
    
    console.log(yoda)
    console.log(characters[0]);
    console.log(characters[1]);
    console.log(characters[2]);
    console.log(characters[3]);
    
    // start the game with a loop that sends the 4 character in the object to a div
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        function startgame() {
            $.each(characters, function(index, character) {
                var characterDiv = $('<div>').addClass('character');
                var characterName = $('<p>').addClass("character-name").text(character.name);
                var characterImg = $("<img>").addClass("character-img").attr('src',
                    character.imgURL);;
                var characterHealth = $('<p>').addClass('character-health').text(character.health);
                characterDiv.append(characterName, characterImg, characterHealth).appendTo('.Character')
            })
        }
        startgame()
    
    
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   
    
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="page header">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <h1><strong>Star Wars RPG</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="Character">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h2><strong>Your Character</strong></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="enemiesavailable">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="attack">
                        <h3>Enemies Available to Attack</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="fighter">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="fight">
                        <h4>Fight Section</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">attack</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h5>Defender</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript " src="assests/javascript/java.js "></script>
  

Jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Cache the DOM first
const pony = document.querySelector('#pony')
// Add a event listener to the #pony element

// Tell JavaScript the event will be a click event
pony.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // Then the user click on the pony element, this callback will be fire up
  
  // Just console log out the silly message I got ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  console.log('You just click a pony :P')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id='pony' src='https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/e9/c1/63e9c1df1e897de2386e31180b9a21b6.jpg' />
```